# Oracle - Как сравнить разницу данных в двух столбцах для таблиц разной структуры

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, table, diff

Мне необходимо выявить разницу в двух таблицах и столбцах с разной структурой.

Таблица А:

| атрибут | компания | код |
| --- | --- | --- |
| цена | rus | AR2 |
| долг | fr | AR3 |
| налог | en | ARY |
| налог | fr | AR5 |
| налог | en | AR10 |
| налог | fr | BRZ |
| налог | en | AVZ |
| налог | fr | AAA |
| налог | en | QZE |
| налог | en | AR5 |

Таблица B:

| филиал | компания | элемент | дата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | rus | AR2 | 09/08/2021 |
| 3456 | fr | AR3 | 01/02/2020 |
| 7890 | en | ARY | 08/01/2021 |
| 5654 | en | AR5 | 08/01/2020 |
| 5654 | en | QZE | 08/01/2020 |
| 5654 | en | HHH | 08/01/2020 |

Необходимо выявить разницу в столбцах Код и Элемент только для случаев, когда компания для обеих таблиц равна 'en' и Атрибут для первой таблицы равен 'налог'

Примерный код для понимания сути:

select A.* from A
left join B on A.компания = B.компания
where A.атрибут = 'налог' and A.компания = 'en'

Конечная таблица будет выглядеть следующим образом:

Таблица С:

| атрибут | компания | код |
| --- | --- | --- |
| налог | en | ARY |
| налог | en | AR10 |
| налог | en | AVZ |
| налог | en | HH |

где первые три столбца показывают разницу данных из первой таблицы, а четвертый столбец - из второй.

Буду благодарна любой помощи и подсказке.

С уважением,

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подзапрос:

```
select A.* 
from A
where A.атрибут = 'налог' 
  and A.компания = 'en'
  AND A.код NOT IN (SELECT B.элемент FROM B where B.компания = 'en')
```

И в другую сторону (что есть в B но нет в A):

```
select B.* 
from B
where B.компания = 'en'
  AND B.элемент NOT IN (SELECT А.код FROM A where A.компания = 'en' AND A.атрибут = 'налог' )
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает. Осталось придумать как это все объединить в один код. Оба случая.

Comment: UNION или UNION ALL можно объединить результаты двух запросов

Comment: Спасибо за совет. К сожалению, UNION и UNION ALL не работают, скорее всего из-за разной структуры таблиц:  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: нужно чтобы запросы, которые вы объединяете, возвращали одинаковое количество колонок одинакового типа. Укажите в SELECT только нужные колонки.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, помогло. Спасибо большое